# How would you write this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, sentence

Concerns of critics become evident in large apps where it is common to see CSS files with thousands of lines of code.

OR

Critics' concern become evident in large apps where it is common to see CSS files with thousands of lines of code.

Comment: For what it's worth, I (weakly) prefer the first one, but both are grammatical. However, this queston may be better suited for [Writing StackExchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first since it seems more direct. I might leave the Concern without the possessive since "Concern of critics" would say the same thing.